# EGit (Eclipse Git Plugin): Mix/merge two commits

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

How can I "mix/merge" two commits in Egit (Git) like this?

Commit 1

```
void test(void) {
    unsigned int foo, bar;

    foo = 42; // Foo 42!


}
```

Commit 2

```
 void test(void) {
    unsigned int foo, bar;

    foo = 10; // Changed var val

    printf("foo = %u", foo);
}
```

New mixed result

```
 void test(void) {
    unsigned int foo, bar;

    foo = 42; // Foo 42!

    printf("foo = %u", foo);
}
```

Commit 2 is actually master(HEAD). I tried to click on Commit 2 (in History) and then "Merge". Message I got was: "Result: Already-up-to-date".

Comment: In git you merge branches, not commits. Can you give us your branches layout? (`git branch` for the local list) and tell which commit is on which branch?

Comment: $ git branch
* master (I have only one "master")

Answer (score 0):

From what you stated in comment (no other branches than `master` in your repo), it seems that your two commits are both on your `master` branch, so there's no merging to be done here.

If these commits were on different branches, you could merge them, you'd have a merge conflict that you'd resolve manually. So I'd suggest to do just that, except not in a merge.

Open your file, and as you seem to know exactly how the file should look, edit it until it's satisfying and commit it. Merge is no magic process, it would involve basically the same questions and actions anyway.

Comment: _"it seems that your two commits are both on your master branch"_ - Yes this is correct.

Comment: _"If these commits were on different branches, you could merge them, you'd have a merge conflict that you'd resolve manually. So I'd suggest to do just that, except not in a merge."_ - So should I open a different branch in that case?

Comment: _"Open your file, and as you seem to know exactly how the file should look, edit it until it's satisfying and commit it."_ - Do you mean, that I should use for e.g. a "diff view" and then solve it by editing manually?

Comment: @TickTacJoe ? No, I meant manually editing the file, then committing the changes. If it's easier for you to start from a diff between commits, so be it, get it with `git diff <commit1> <commit2>` then edit manually as needed.

Comment: Pure manually editing is that, what I try to avoid with my approach.  I thought there could be a mechanism in EGit that could make it semi automatic (like showing me a preview). So the only thing I could do is to make a branch for that file?

Comment: @TickTacJoe it's a bit difficult to answer since I don't know the specifics of your config and workflow, and specifically what I don't get is how you managed to have a file with conflicting (n-1) and (n-2) versions. I can't say if it would be better in your situation to have another branch layout/strategy. Is this a recurring problem? If so, we'd have to spot the reasons why, if not just amend the present situation manually and keep moving :-)

Comment: I am new to Git so I do not have a specific workflow yet... But I often have this kind of conflict situation. That's because I'm currently programming for micro controllers. There are, for instance, a lot bit flags, which I often later correct / change. For such and similar situations, I was looking for an easy way to reinsert older pieces of code into the current file version.

Comment: @TickTacJoe Hmmm, ok it's a bit clearer now, so you're prone to have frequent back-and-forth modifications on the same files / same lines. For one thing I'd suggest to have atomic commits when it's possible (one modification per commit, not a bunch of them in one), it'll be easier to specifically spot / revert.